# Find a continuous PDF on $[0,6]$ for given probabilities

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions

> Find a *continuous* probability density function $f$ on $[0,6]$, such that $\mathbb{P}([0,2]) = 0.6$, $\mathbb{P}([1,4]) = 0.5$ and $\mathbb{P}([3,5]) = 0.2$.

After some calculations I came up with the piecewise constant function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{3}{10},&0\le x< 2\\\frac{1}{10},&2\le x\le6\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ But then I noticed that the question asks for a continuous PDF. I then tried to fit some polynomials like $f(x) = ax^2$ and $ax^2 + bx$, but this becomes tedious very fast. What is a good approach to find a simple cont. PDF like this one?

Comment: $\frac{3}{10}+\frac{1}{10}+0<1$.

Comment: $2\frac{3}{10} + 4\frac{1}{10} = 1$.

Comment: @JimmyR.: Yep, sorry, the integrals on each section should sum up to $1$. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Instead of choosing $f$ piecewise constant, you can choose $f$ piecewise linear, $$f(x)=\begin{cases}a_1x+b_1,&0\le x< 2\\a_2x+b_2,&2\le x< 4\\a_3x+b_3,&4\le x< 6\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ in a way that $f$ is continuous in $x=0,2,4,6$.

---

Start with $$\int_{0}^2(a_1x+b_1)\ dx=0.6$$ Since $f(0)=0$ (for continuity) this implies that $b_1=0$ and you find that $a_1=0.3$. So, $f(x)=0.3x$ in $0\le x<2$. Next, you get that $$P([1,2])=\int_{1}^20.3x\ dx=0.45$$ (here $P([1,2])$ is a shortcut for $P(X\in[1,2])$) and hence $$P([2,4])=P([1,4])-P([1,2])=0.05$$ So, to establish the second part of $f$ know you need to solve $$\int_{2}^{4}a_2x+b_2 \ dx=0.05$$ under the restriction that $f(2)=0.6$. Can you take it?

---

Most direct approaches, i.e. choosing $f$ piecewise linear or piecewise constant (like the ones presented above) will present computational difficulties for a single reason: the overlapping intervals. So the first thing you should do is to split in disjoint intervals in a way that is consistent with the given probabilities. My choice $$P([0,1])=0.4, \ P([1,2])=0.2, \ P([2,3])=0.2, \ P([3,4])=0.1, \ P([4,5])=0.1$$
Now the solution follows immediately by choosing $f$ to be piecewise quadratic with roots the bounds of each interval: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(x-0)(x-1),&0\le x< 1\\c_2(x-1)(x-2),&1\le x< 2\\c_3(x-2)(x-3),&2\le x< 3\\c_4(x-3)(x-4),&3\le x< 4\\c_5(x-4)(x-5),&4\le x< 5\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Since the intervals do not overlap there is much leeway in the choice of $f$ in each interval. The previous choice is one possibility, another one would be triangle distribution in each interval and many more (that preserve continuity of course). So, now start solving $$P([k,k+1])=\int_{k}^{k+1}c_k(x-k)(x-(k+1))dx$$ for $0\le k\le 4$.

Comment: Thanks, Jimmy. Did you perhaps mean $f(2)=0.6$?.

Comment: @jazzinsilhouette Yes, corrected! thanks

Comment: I'm always getting $-\frac{23}{40}(x-3) + \frac{1}{40}$ for $2 \leq x < 4$. Which is negative after about $x = 3$. This shouldn't happen, right? Some more suggestions? Maybe we have to change the interval boundaries?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will try something else.

Comment: @jazzinsilhouette I proposed a way that works, but can you check please that your data is correct? You say in the first line that you rv is supported in $[0,6]$ but then you give probabilities up to $5$. It is not a problem, but is it indeed so, thanks?

Comment: Thanks again, Jimmy. The support really is supposed to be $[0,6]$. This was a problem on one of the sheets of a course on probability that I attended. Unfortunately they didn't give a solution...

Comment: Ok, but your given data gives probabilities up to $5$ and not up to $6$. In any case, the above approach solves it. If you want to stay linear then choose triangle distribution in each subinterval.